# startxwin - xinit unable to connect to X server

Tags: cygwin

After updating to the latest Cygwin distribution, I can no longer connect to X server.  When I run startxwin (on a fresh Cygwin install), I get the following errors:

> xinit: giving up 
>   xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
>   xinit: server error

The XWin.#.log looks okay (I think):

> Could not load crashreporter dll
>   Welcome to the XWin X Server
>   Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
>   Release: 1.17.1.0
>   OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW ENDYMION 2.0.2(0.287/5/3) 2015-05-08 17:03 i686
>   OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (WoW64)
>   Package: version 1.17.1-4 built 2015-05-01
>   
>   XWin was started with the following command line:
>   
>   /usr/bin/XWin :4 -multiwindow -auth 
>    /home/clkunz/.serverauth.8376 
>   
>   ddxProcessArgument - Initializing default screens
>   winInitializeScreenDefaults - primary monitor w 1920 h 1200
>   winInitializeScreenDefaults - native DPI x 96 y 96
>   [ 10857.934] Could not load crashreporter dll
>   [ 10857.965] (II) xorg.conf is not supported
>   [ 10857.965] (II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
>   [ 10857.965] LoadPreferences: /home/clkunz/.XWinrc not found
>   [ 10857.965] LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
>   [ 10857.965] LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
>   [ 10857.981] winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
>   [ 10858.012] winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005

Comment: This is a system administration problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: Did you set the environment variable `DISPLAY` to `localhost:0.0` or `:0.0` in your case ? Could be that.

Comment: Yep, DISPLAY is set to :0.0.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the command line there calls for it to be on `:4`, which is probably short for `:4.4`.

Answer (score 0):

This [recent cygwin link](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-05/msg00185.html) shows one failure mode related to Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP) not working with the 32-bit version of XWin on 64-bit machines.

One solution (if that's the problem) is to add an exception for XWin.exe to SEP; or you can also disable SEM while you invoke XWin.

To add a SEP exception, open SEP, Change Settings -> Exceptions [Configure Settings].

To disable SEP, right click on the icon in the system tray, and disable it all.  Start XWin.  Don't forget to turn SEP back on.